# why is String lost when it enters the first loop?

Tags: c

in the following code, I ran into a problem where I had a string from getString method then it was fine until I entered the loop, then I lost the string. I don't know why I lost the sting it should be within the stack.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[1]){
    char * str;
    getString(str, 100000);
    char * ID[100];
    int num[100];
    for(int i =0 ; i < 100; i ++){
        num[i]=0;
    }
    int j = 0; 
    for(int i =0; i < sizeof(str);i++){
        if( str[i] == '<'){
            char * strPoint = (str+i+1);
            int ln = findLenth(strPoint);
            char * strCom = malloc(ln*sizeof(char));
            memcpy(strCom, str, ln);
            int r = tag(ID, strCom, &j);
            if(r != -1){
                num[r]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int r = 0; r <j; r++){
        printf("%s     %d\n", ID[r], num[r]);
        
    }
    freeMemory(ID, j);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void getString(char* str, int i){
    fgets (str, i, stdin);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(str)` is sizeof a pointer, probably 8 (or 4), not the underlying size allocated nor the length of the string (use `strlen()` for the length)

Comment: Also, `str` is uninitialized. It points to who knows what.

Comment: ok that answer to something I was going to solve later

Comment: are you saying all I had to do was allocate memory

Comment: That and using the correct length function should at least get you farther.

Comment: well I thank you now that is no longer a problime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `str` is uninitialized. There's no telling what it points to. You'll need to allocate some space with `malloc` or something and initialize `str` with that.

Second, your loop uses `sizeof(str)`. While this is legal even with `str` uninitialized, it will not give you the length you are looking for. It will give you the size of the *pointer*, not what it points to. It would probably work better to call `strlen(str)`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `getString()` is defined at the bottom of the posted code, and allocates nothing. It also cannot modify `str` (other than locally).

Comment: Thank you Fred! I guess I am blind in one eye and can't read out of the other....